# How to create a WLAN hotspot on a laptop in XFCE4?

Tags: fedora, xfce, wlan, wifi-hotspot

I've been looking through a couple of manuals and tutorials, most [concerning Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/software_access_point), but I seem to be finding slightly contradicting things.

So, I use XFCE4 on Fedora 23, and the network manager that comes with that (`nm-applet`).

I'd like to create a WLAN hotspot with the WLAN adapter in the laptop I'm using, and bridging that with the wired connection of the laptop.

I was unable to do that.

The network manager tries to connect to another WLAN network it sees, even when instructed to enable the Hotspot or Ad-Hoc modes I've configured.

when running `iw phy0 info`, the supported modes list looks like this:

```
Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * monitor
```

which leaves me wondering, if AP (which is missing in that list) mode is even possible.

I can only assume, that once having configured the WLAN-AP, I'd then have to configure a bridge with both the WLAN device and the Ethernet device bridged together.